No water in icemaker
Installed a gfci outlet. It tripped and after resetting it the refrigerator is working but now not getting water in the icemaker. Just Installed a new water inlet valve before gfci tripped. Checked the continuity on valve and it registered 213 ohms. I have ordered a new icemaker W11729596 per Whirlpool recommendation for my Estate REFRIGERATOR TT21AKXKT03. It has 5-pin connector on both ends, but my freezer has a 4-pin connector. Cannot find an adapter for it and cannot find the correct icemaker with the 4-pin connectors. Is there something I can repair on current icemaker (628407) or is there an adapter or what icemaker will work with 4-pin connector?

W11729596 is a genuine OEM ice maker kit that replaces W11510803 which has 4 wires

213 Ohm is to high, it should be more like 10 ohm

DIY75 -- I was told by a vendor that W11510803 has a 5-pin with 4 wires. That is the problem I keep running into. When I enter 5-pin to 4-pin search results always comeback 5-pin 4 wires. Not 4-pin. Frustrating

Does your W11729596 have 5 pins and 5 wires?  Also, when you say "both ends" what do you mean?  Is the cable a separate part that has connectors on both ends?

Also, PartSelect shows the W11510803—not W11729596—as the replacement for the TT21AKXKT03.

It has 5 pins but only 4 wires on both ends of the harness. . One of the pins are empty. It is identical on both ends with the only exception is one end is female and the other end is male. W11729596  is the icemaker Whirlpool informed me per phone which is the replacement for W11510803. The installation instructions states that the kit has "2" jumper harnesses. Use the one that fits and discard the other harness. Whirlpool insisted that it only comes with "1" harness and it is the 5-pin 4 wire on both ends. They wanted me to pay $135 for the other harness and it was a special order 4-6 weeks
